# multiple Turtlebot3 navigation and simulation

Tags: navigation, simulation, ros-kinetic, multiple, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the relative source [Multiple robots simulation and navigation](https://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/).

I need to launch a turtlebot3 with navigation, and others can be controlled by teleop.
My questions are: 1. Why my launch file doesn't work  2. Can I use the launch file to load the models in gazebo and use the second part of Multiple robots simulation and navigation.

I tried to compile the launch file, according to the link:Multiple robots simulation and navigation and [Turtlebot3](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/#simulation).

First, I tried to copy the Multiple robots simulation and navigation.

```
one_robot.launch
    <launch>
        <arg name="robot_name"/>
        <arg name="init_pose"/>
        <node name="spawn_minibot_model" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model"
              args="$(arg init_pose) -urdf -param /robot_description -model $(arg robot_name)"
              respawn="false" output="screen" />
        <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher"
              name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen"/>
        <!-- The odometry estimator, throttling, fake laser etc. go here -->
        <!-- All the stuff as from usual robot launch file -->
    </launch>
```

then robots.launch

```
<launch>
    <!-- No namespace here as we will share this description.
         Access with slash at the beginning -->
    <!--param name="robot_description"
           command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find turtlebot_description)/urdf/turtlebot.urdf.xacro" /-->

    <!-- BEGIN ROBOT 1-->

    <group ns="robot1">
        <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot1_tf" />
        <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />
        <include file="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/launch/one_robot.launch" >
            <arg name="init_pose" value="-x 1 -y 1 -z 0" />
            <arg name="robot_name"  value="Robot1" />
        </include>
    </group>

    <!-- BEGIN ROBOT 2-->
    <group ns="robot2">
        <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot2_tf" />
        <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />
        <include file="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/launch/one_robot.launch" >
            <arg name="init_pose" value="-x -1 -y 1 -z 0" />
            <arg name="robot_name"  value="Robot2" />
        </include>
    </group>
</launch>
```

new_simulation.launch

```
<launch>
    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />
    <!-- start world -->
    <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo"
          args="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/worlds/turtlebot3_world.world" respawn="false" output="screen" />
    <!-- start gui -->
    <node name="gazebo_gui" pkg="gazebo" type="gui" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
    <!-- include our robots -->
    <include file="$(turtlebot3_gazebo)/launch/robots.launch"/>
</launch>
```

Up to now, I think the first part of launch the models in Gazebo. However, it doesn't.

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo new_simulation.launch 
... logging to /home/ise-admin/.ros/log/c26e921e-a106-11e8-841a-509a4c311940/roslaunch-ise-linux-1-25593.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Unknown substitution command [turtlebot3_gazebo]. Valid commands are ['find', 'env', 'optenv', 'anon', 'arg']
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

The original launch multi TB3 in Gazebo on TB3 emanual is:

```
    <launch>
  <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
  <arg name="first_tb3"  default="tb3_0"/>
  <arg name="second_tb3" default="tb3_1"/>
  <arg name="third_tb3"  default="tb3_2"/>

  <arg name="first_tb3_x_pos" default="-2.0"/>
  <arg name="first_tb3_y_pos" default="-1.0"/>
  <arg name="first_tb3_z_pos" default=" 0.0"/>
  <arg name="first_tb3_yaw"   default=" 0.0"/>

  <arg name="second_tb3_x_pos" default=" 2.0"/>
  <arg name="second_tb3_y_pos" default="-1.0"/>
  <arg name="second_tb3_z_pos" default=" 0.0"/>
  <arg name="second_tb3_yaw"   default=" 0.0"/>

  <arg name="third_tb3_x_pos" default=" 0.5"/>
  <arg name="third_tb3_y_pos" default=" 2.0"/>
  <arg name="third_tb3_z_pos" default=" 0.0"/>
  <arg name="third_tb3_yaw"   default=" 0.0"/>

  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/worlds/turtlebot3_world.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  </include>  

  <group ns = "$(arg first_tb3)">
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen">
      <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
      <param name="tf_prefix" value="$(arg first_tb3)" />
    </node>
    
    <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -model $(arg first_tb3) -x $(arg first_tb3_x_pos) -y $(arg first_tb3_y_pos) -z $(arg first_tb3_z_pos) -Y $(arg first_tb3_yaw) -param robot_description" />
  </group>

  <group ns = "$(arg second_tb3)">
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen">
      <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
      <param name="tf_prefix" value="$(arg second_tb3)" />
    </node>

    <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -model $(arg second_tb3) -x $(arg second_tb3_x_pos) -y $(arg second_tb3_y_pos) -z $(arg second_tb3_z_pos) -Y $(arg second_tb3_yaw) -param robot_description" />
  </group>

  <group ns = "$(arg third_tb3)">
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen">
      <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
      <param name="tf_prefix" value="$(arg third_tb3)" />
    </node>

    <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -model $(arg third_tb3) -x $(arg third_tb3_x_pos) -y $(arg third_tb3_y_pos) -z $(arg third_tb3_z_pos) -Y $(arg third_tb3_yaw) -param robot_description" />
  </group>


</launch>
```

Thank you for reading such long material. Thank you very much!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300693/multiple-turtlebot3-navigation-and-simulation/) by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2018-08-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) on 2018-08-16**:
=>Unknown substitution command [turtlebot3_gazebo]. Valid commands are ['find', 'env', 'optenv', 'anon', 'arg']

I think the `turtlebot3_gazebo` package are not included in your workspace

**Comment by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on 2018-08-16**:
No, I can find them by rospack find turtlebot3_gazebo. Anyway thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In new_simulation.launch, you're missing the word find.

```
<include file="$(turtlebot3_gazebo)/launch/robots.launch"/>
```

should be

```
<include file="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/launch/robots.launch"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0